# Eager loading relation when relation is defined by finder_sql - ignores finder_sql and build default has_many query

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many, eager-loading

There is class called `Location`. I would like to to preload all direct children within a single query.

In `Location` class relation is defined like:

```
has_many :children,
  class_name: self,
  finder_sql: ->(query) {
      self.class.where(%Q{"locations"."ancestry" like '%#{id}'}).to_sql
  },
  counter_sql: ->(query) {
    self.class.where(%Q{"locations"."ancestry" like '%#{id}'}).count.to_sql
  }


Location.first.children
  Location Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" LIMIT 1
  Location Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE ("locations"."ancestry" like '%1')
  => [#<Location id: 2, code: nil, name: "Niger 1349875728.873964", alternative_name: nil, ancestry: "1", coordinates: nil, ancestry_depth: 1>, (...)]
```

But when I want to optimize this and load everything in just two batches:

```
Location.includes(:children).where(id: [5, 100]).all
  Location Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."id" IN (5, 100)
  Location Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."location_id" IN ('5')
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column locations.location_id does not exist
  LINE 1: SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations"  WHERE "locations"."lo...
                                                 ^
  : SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations"  WHERE "locations"."location_id" IN ('5')
  from /xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@gsp/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1158:in `async_exec'
```

Is this a bug in Rails, or should I define it in a different way?

I'm also trying to overwrite find_in_collection on relation but it has no impact.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you're fighting Rails a bit too much there. Use the condition param on has_many:

```
has_many :children, class_name: self, conditions: [%Q{"locations"."ancestry" like '%#{id}'}]
```

Also just wondering about the use of like there? Why not test for =?

```
has_many :children, class_name: self, foreign_key: :ancestry
```

Further, that should stylistically have an _id if you go that route:

```
has_many :children, class_name: self, foreign_key: :ancester_id
```